# Windows XP - Blue Screen

Tags: windows-xp, troubleshooting, bios, bsod

I have a Dell Latitude D810 I found in our IT storage in basement (computer graveyard) that I was going to use for parts, specifically the keyboard.  When I found it, it had a note on it "Blue Screen, Dispose".  It's not a bad spec machine so I was curious if it could be fixed.

It boots into Windows and soon after a blue screen appears.  I tried a reformat and fresh installation of Windows might help but soon after another blue screen.

It states:

A problem has been detected and windows has been shut down to prevent damange to your computer.  If this is the first time you've seen this stop error screen, restart your computer.  If this screen appears again, follow these steps:

Check to be sure you have adequate disk space.  If a driver is identified in the stop message, disable the driver or check with the manufacturer for driver updates.  Try changing video adapters.

Check with your hardware vendor for any BIOS updates.  Disable BIOS memory options such as cashing or shadowing.  If you need to use safe mode to remove or disable components, restart your computer, press F8 to select advanced startup options, and the select safe mode.

Technical Information:
*** STOP 0x0000008E (0xc0000005, 0x805B03F5, 0xF703DC7C, 0x00000000)

Beginning dump of physical memory
Physical memory dump complete.
Contact you system administrator or technical support group for further assistance.

My main question is what is this Technical Information telling me?  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Ah, the classic "technical information" to refer to your "system administrator"... Like if they could read through hexa error numbers :)

Comment: Blue screens in xp are almost always a bad driver or bad hardware. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) on it to test for any memory errors.  Be sure to let it complete a few passes -- I've seen some modules pass the first pass then fail the second.  If you receive errors, start testing each memory module individually to weed-out the defective module.  Once you identify the defective module, replace it and enjoy your working laptop.

Comment: I ran memtest 86, it completed the first pass without any errors.  I am now letting it complete additional passes.  If the issue is not with a defective memory module, what is my next action?

Comment: There is some more advice on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315335

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft suggests it could be something [wrong with RAM modules](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315335).

[Here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/stop0x0000008e.htm) is also a detailed post about the error and possible solutions.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be interested to know if it crashes when booted from a live CD (ubuntu, bartpe etc.), if it doesn't it might indicate a hard disk issue. Also if you do use an ubuntu live CD it would probably be worth trying a memtest86 (not memcheck86 as previously stated thanks to eleven81 for the correction) from the boot menu to see if there is a memory issue.

Comment: I believe it's memtest86, not memcheck86, that you meant!

Comment: If it is a hard disk issue... Should I be able to just throw a working hard drive in the machine and be good to go?  I do have other junker laptops available to use as parts.

Comment: Yup similarly if it's a memory it's usually just swap one SODIMM for another with the same spec.

Comment: @eleven81 You're probably right I'll amend it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some info from Microsoft.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827663
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945658

Answer (score 2):

8B indicates faulty memory.

replace the memory module (RAM is cheap enough these days, [1 GB DDR2 PC2-5300 < $20](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=Latitude%20D810#), this model takes up to 2 GB) and give it a new lease of life :)

Answer (score 0):

check the ram in the laptop.  since it's a dell, i'm suspecting it's their dreaded 'hynix' memory.  i've yet to see a computer that didn't have trouble with hynix.  i've followed that blue screen to hynix ram on many occasions....

Comment: Ran memtest86... 4 passes, no errors.

Comment: passes aren't going to matter.  i've run the memory test with perfect results everytime and yet when i replace the ram(in the case of dell, hynix ram), no more blue screens and the pc works perfectly from then on.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with dells, its always the RAM, take out 1 stick of ram if you can, if not replace it

Comment: Ran memtest86... 4 passes, no errors.