# Why does Firefox crash then pops with a BSOD error?

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise on a new Samsung QX411 laptop. I've installed the OS recently.

Sometimes (a few times so far) when I'm using Firefox, it suddenly crashes repeatably and a few seconds later I get a BSOD. I then restart and it's fine.

I've run `CHKDSK /F` as suggested in the blue screen and the driver of the hardware seems to be up to date.

Any suggestions what I need to do?

Comment: There's not much to go off of here, something that could help is type "view all problem reports" and press enter. From there you should be able to locate various crashes within your system and it may help pinpoint the system which is having issues.

Comment: Which version of Firefox?  4? 5? 6?

How much memory do you have (physical and virtual)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Blue Screens (BSODs) are a tricky thing to diagnose yourself, let alone here on SuperUser.

You should follow a few guides to help you gather more info and self diagnose, then you can report back and modify the question with much more specific details if you can't solve it. You need to be very specific with exact hardware, memory amount, service packs, application version numbers, and if you can cause the error with other apps.

Have a look at the answers on these these questions/blogs:

> [How to diagnose Blue Screens in Windows 7 (64bit)](https://superuser.com/questions/28448/how-to-diagnose-blue-screens-in-windows-7-64bit)
>
> [Windows 7 x64 blue screen of death](https://superuser.com/questions/79731/windows-7-x64-blue-screen-of-death)
>
> If you suspect a memory issue (firefox uses a fair bit of memory when heavily used), tests like [MemTest86](http://www.memtest86.com/)
>
> [Windows XP - Blue Screen](https://superuser.com/questions/42635/windows-xp-blue-screen)
>
> http://www.techradar.com/news/computing/how-to-diagnose-and-fix-blue-screen-crashes-595800
>
> http://mintywhite.com/windows-7/7maintenance/diagnose-understand-windows-blue-screens-bsod-guide/

Answer (score 0):

If your BSOD is of the `0x124` type, you may want to check in the direction of malware as well. A problem very similar to yours has been haunting my system for a long time. It look like I am finally making [some progress](https://superuser.com/questions/389123/firefox-always-the-one-causing-bsod-0x124-on-windows-7-64-bit).